# C - Read and set assembler registers

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, cpu-registers

I need to be able to access assembly registers from my C code. I there a easy way to set the value of a register to the value of a variable and get the value of a register as a variable?? Hope this makes sense...

Comment: there is an inline __asm function in C.

Comment: Also, inline asm is different depending on compiler. Msvc's inline asm is much easier than gcc's

Comment: I am using the gcc compiler.

Comment: "Hope this makes sense..." - Definitely: No. The C compiler will create assembler code from the C code, so when running a C program you are actually running an assembler program. This assembler program of course uses (and modifies) the registers. Writing to the CPU registers from a C program will of course have the same effect as adding instructions writing to some registers at random (!!) lines of an assembler program: The program may crash...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using VC (Microsoft's C compiler)

```
int regVal;
__asm {
  mov [regVal], eax
}
```

That would load whatever `eax` is holding into `regVal`

If you're using GCC:

```
int regVal;
asm("movl %%eax, %0" : "=r"(regVal) :);
```

Hopefully I got this right, I don't actually do inline assembly in GCC.

Comment: Cool. How do i set a register?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft or the GNU one? If the first one: *mov eax, [regVal]*, if the second one I think it is: *asm("movl %0, %%eax" : : "r"(regVal))*

Comment: @Matthew: Writing to `%eax` without telling the compiler about it will step on whatever the compiler was using EAX for.  You need to declare a clobber on `eax`, or use `asm volatile("" : : "a"(regVal));` to get the compiler to put `regVal` in EAX for you.

Comment: @Ciro: your edit was unnecessary.  My comment was replying to a comment that omitted an `"=a"`, *not* about the answer.  The answer was fine, and declaring a clobber on EAX will unnecessarily stop the compiler from keeping a value there.  You can read any register you want without declaring a clobber on it.  It's not *useful* if you have no idea what's going to be in that register (see my answer), but it won't break compiler-generated code.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to know the value of a register while some code is executing, it makes *much* more sense to use a debugger.  (Like gdb with `layout asm; layout reg`).  Seeing register values without also seeing the asm code makes little sense.

See the links and guides in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki.

---

However, with GNU inline asm, you could just do something like

```
int eax_snapshot;
asm volatile (
    ""
    : "=a" (eax_snapshot)
    // no inputs, no clobbers
);
// any amount of intervening code
printf("eax was %x\n", eax_snapshot);  // print whatever eax had at the point where the inline asm appeared in program order
```

[The `a` constraint](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints) means the operand must use the `%eax` register.  The body of your inline asm then becomes a no-op, because your output operand is already where you told the compiler it will be.

There's no guarantee that gcc won't emit code that clobbers `%eax` before the asm block.  This is why it makes little sense to do this.  `volatile` tells the compiler not to re-order the asm statement with respect to other source instructions, but optimizations could still mean that earlier initializations are folded into later code that uses them.  Or vice versa.  Using a combination of this with an explicit-register local variable might help avoid gcc using your chosen register as a scratch register for computing other things, though.  (see below).

---

To set a register, use inline asm with an `"a"` constraint to force that operand's value to be in `%eax` (or `%ebx` for a `"b"` constraint, etc, see the docs for the x86-specific machine constraints) at the point where the inline asm appears.  If you want to actually *use* that register value, do it from inside the inline asm statement, or else the register may be overwritten with something else.

---

You can also declare variables the must be allocated in a specific register, but I think using them without initialization makes the compiler unhappy.  (Code transformation passes that detect undefined behaviour such as this could cause a problem.  IDK.)  The syntax would be

```
register int eax asm ("eax");  // don't do this to read eax, it probably doesn't do what you think it would
```

[The docs make it sound like using it for reading registers is not going to be a good idea.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html#Local-Register-Variables)  However, for setting a register value, this may work.  (As long as the register allocator takes your hint and does keep that variable in the requested register.)

`register int foo asm("regname")` sometimes still works in practice with GCC the way it used to (before they changed the documentation to unsupport it except for inline asm). But IIRC not always.

Clang generally doesn't do anything beyond constraining what choices `"r"` or `"=r"` makes for an Extended asm statement, the minimum the GCC documentation guarantees.  So even if the now-undocumented (and thus unsupported) usage of it without an actual `asm` statement happens to work on your version of GCC for your code for reading or writing a register at some point in your program, it's likely not portable to clang.

---

**Don't do this** unless you have a very good reason.  It's highly unlikely to be useful for normal programming.  Normal inline asm, or calling functions, is a better way to combine C and asm.  This is only useful if you want some kind of kludgy poking at the internal state of your program.

Reading a register this way inside a normal function means the compiler could have put some instructions before your `asm` statement which modify that register, so you can't be sure it actually came from an asm caller, if you're trying to invent a custom calling convention.

Since you haven't given a use-case for why you want this, I strongly urge you not to write code that does this.  It just sounds ugly.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using gcc, here are the docs on using the asm template in gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#AssemblerTemplate

In order to set the value of a register, you would do the following:

```
uint64_t rax = 0;
__asm__ __volatile__("mov %0, %%rax\n\t"
                     : /* no output */
                     : "a" (rax)
                     : "%rax");
```

In order to read the value of a register, you would do the following:

```
uint64_t rax;
__asm__ __volatile__("mov %%rax, %0\n\t"
                     : "=a"(rax)
                     : /* no input */
                     : /* no clobbers */);
```

Comment: I think you want the clobber (RAX) on the first code snippet, not the second. Will admit this isn't particularly useful. Can also be simplified by using `=a` and `a` constraint rather than `=r` and `r`

Comment: Ah yes thanks for catching the clobbers; mixed those up while writing the snippet.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this isn't useful. It's actually the only factual answer which directly answers the question for gcc (which is what the question is about) without any opinions about whether or not this is a good thing to do.